# Problem with 6.30.223.248+bdcom in Precise

Tags: wireless, lenovo, broadcom

For the benefit of others, I just wanted to report here, that I suddenly began to notice an extremely unstable wlan on my Lenovo G700 still running Precise. Things were fine as soon as I moved close to the router, but one floor down in my house it got slow and erratic.

The card is a Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01).

After searching various forums I now downgraded using

bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.2_amd64.deb (which from the dpkg logs I identified as the previously installed version, until some 4 weeks ago or so)

and my wlan is back to the previous excellent performance. I think it should be possible to lock this version of bcmwl by generating a file

/etc/apt/preferences.d/bcmwl-kernel-source

containing the lines

```
Package: bcmwl-kernel-source
Pin: version 6.20.155.1+bdcom*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Hope this helps somebody ...

Comment: You better find a question with a similar problem and answer it. Or write a question and an answer. It will be much more helpful.